# Android nested ViewPager's fragments dont show after switch between Fragments on Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my application i have one Activity and that have some fragments and i can switch between fragments without any problem. one of this fragments have `ViewPager` with some other fragments, after switch between parent fragments abd back to nested fragment with viewPager, nested fragments dont show and i must be close application and run again to show that.

Main Activity:

```
public void updateFragment(int selectedItem) {
    mFragment = null;
    fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (selectedItem) {
        case 0:
            mFragment = new FragmentMainView();
            break;
        case 1:
            mFragment = new FragmentAddNewWayBill();
            break;
    }
    fts.replace(R.id.mainViewFragments, mFragment, "0");
    fts.commit();
    mDrawerState = false;
}
```

in this code i can switch between fragments. `FragmentMainView()` have ViewPager with some defined fragments.

```
public class FragmentMainView extends Fragment {
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ViewPager vpPager;
    private FragmentManager fragManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_view, container, false);

        G.currentActivity = FragmentMainView.this.getActivity();
        fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
        vpPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(fragManager);
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

        return view;
    }

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return FragmentOne.newInstance(0);
                case 1:
                    return FragmentTwo.newInstance(1);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String tabHeaderTitle = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tabHeaderTitle = UC.getString(R.string.waybill_register_package_owner);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tabHeaderTitle = UC.getString(R.string.create_new_waybill);
                    break;
            }
            return tabHeaderTitle;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

in first switch on `FragmentMainView()` in `MainActivity` fragments on `FragmentMainView()` into ViewPager work correctly and show, but after switch on `FragmentAddNewWayBill()` in `MainActivity` and switch again to `FragmentMainView()` fragments on viewPager dont show and i must be close application and switch again to show that. whats problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `myContext.getSupportFragmentManager()` when using nested fragments.

Comment: your purpose is i must be use `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager` in `FragmentMainView` ? i get this error for that: `can not resolve method  `getSupportFragmentManager`

Comment: Yes. You need to replace `fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();` with `fragManager = getChildFragmentManager();`

Comment: i get this error for that: `can not resolve method getSupportFragmentManager`

Comment: Use `getFragmentManager();`