# FragmentPagerAdapter does not redraw its item Fragments and show blank layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

My `fragment` (one of the parent fragments) has a `ViewPager`, and that `ViewPager` will load a number of child fragments by using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

I observed the child fragments will show properly first time after application run, and after that the child fragments will show blank after I move to other parent fragment and come back to that parent `fragment`. One of the child `fragment` will redraw properly if I swipe to the last child `fragment`.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed, this is a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115726/android-nested-viewpagers-fragments-dont-show-after-switch-between-fragments-on?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent fragment onCreateView, use getChildFragmentManager() when create FragmentPagerAdapter.

Instead of using

```
XXXAdapter xxxAdapter = new XXXAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Use

```
XXXAdapter xxxAdapter = new XXXAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: You answered your own question

Comment: @pepperjack he or she posted question and then answered it at the same time. If he or she knows the answer then why he or she asked ?

Comment: @AdityaSonel He had a epiphany Lol

Comment: @AdityaSonel Some people just want to spread information I guess... sometimes programming language developers or code library managers. Some people start writing the question, realize the problem, and answer it just to not have the time spent on writing the question go to waste.

Comment: Yes, I am here to share my solution, as it took me whole morning to find out. Hope it can save other's time.

Comment: Then its ok bro @Shiyu